# Putting two graphs aside with the command \hskip

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I tried to put aside two graphs of functions with the command \hskip but it seem that it doesn't work. Instead the two graphs start to move away vertically as i vary (x) in the command \hskip (x) pt. What is a simple way to put them aside ? (I use Texstudio). This is the code:

```
begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot[color=red,domain=-10:10, 
samples=1263, 
color=red,]{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\hskip 2pt
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
surf,
]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: a tikzpicture is like a letter, if you go `XX` they come side by side, if you go `X<blank line>X` they are in separate paragraphs and stack vertically.

Comment: How i should write the code in order to come side by side?

Comment: As I said, it is exactly the same as a letter, they would come side by side by default if you did not have a blank line putting them in separate paragraphs. The `\hskip` should use the latex form `\hspace{2pt}`%` and the blank line before it has to go.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My fault was that i didn't make it as 1 tickzpicture. Thanks for the answer